# Building Magento - how to keep code and CMS in sync

Tags: magento, continuous-integration, magento-1.7

We are developing with Magento 1.7.0.2, we are having problem of keeping our code and our CMS page in sync. Let say I have a branch that task include

1. Create a new CMS page
2. Use jQuery slider to display products on this new CMS page

We create a new CMS page in Magento admin. We then add jquery.js and js for slider, and write js function to slide all products inside the main `div` of the new CMS page. However, when we check code into our branch, we only able to checkin the `js` files. So people are assigned to review this task, they only able to pull the `js` code, but not the CMS page, which I think locate inside the database. Therefore, they are unable to test, since I dont have the CMS page. I am thinking of couples way:

1. Passing the db around. This is not a solution, because it is big, and will take long time to import.
2. point db connection in app/etc/local.xml to the remote db that contain the CMS page. Also not a valid solution, because magento store url in database under `web/unsecure/base_url`. So I will always get redirect to the other machine ip address instead of my local ip address.

So how do I resolve this issue? What are industry accepted method for this?Please help? THank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to place full content outside of block code and use only its template?

1. Let's say you have static page 'Slider-2014'. In WYSIWYG editor you place

   ```
   {{widget type="cms/widget_block" template="customjs/slider-2014.phtml"}}
   ```
2. In app/design/frontend/base/default/template/ create folder 'customjs'
3. In folder customjs create file slider-2014.phtml and place anything you need to show in slideshow:

   ```
   <div class="slider"></div>
   ```
4. Clear cache if needed. Then reload /slider-2014.html page and you'll get all content from that file. Now you can share folder customjs